# Segfault when dereferencing iterator for vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dereference

I have a vector of object pointers

```
    std::vector<Element*> elements;
```

When iterating through the vector, I would like to double dereference the iterator in order to call the object's methods.

```
    std::cout << (*it)->getName() << std::endl;
```

This leads to a segfault. The relevant code is below.

I am thinking that the problem is with how I am initializing the vector, because I could move the for-loop to be in the method `initialize()` and it works fine. In `takeTurn()`, the vector is of the appropriate size and the pointers contain the correct addresses. Does this mean that the objects being pointed to are being prematurely destroyed?

main.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Element.h"

    std::vector<Element*> elements;

void initialize() {
    Element ice = Element("ice",1);
    Element fire = Element("fire",2);
    elements.push_back(&ice); 
    elements.push_back(&fire);
}

void takeTurn() {
    std::vector<Element*>::iterator it;
    for(it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << (*it)->getName() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    initialize();
    takeTurn();
    return 0;
}
```

Element.h:

```
#include <string>

class Element {
    public:
        Element(std::string name, int id);
        int getID() { return id_; }
        std::string getName() { return name_; }

    private:
        int id_;
        std::string name_;
};
```

Element.cpp:

```
#include "Element.h"

Element::Element(std::string name, int id) {
    name_ = name;
    id_ = id;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initialize function is broken.  You create local objects, and then push their addresses onto the vector.  But when the function returns, those objects are destroyed, and the pointers are no longer valid.  The simplest fix, unless you need polymorphism, is to just make a vector of Element objects, instead of pointers.

```
std::vector<Element> elements;
...
elements.push_back(Element("ice",1));
elements.push_back(Element("fire",2));
```

If you need polymorphism, then use smart pointers.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element>> elements;
...
elements.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Element>(new Element("ice",1)));
elements.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Element>(new Element("fire",2)));
```

If you were to continue to use raw pointers, then you would need some way to ensure the persistence of the objects, perhaps by allocating them with `new`.  You would then need to ensure you call `delete` on each of those pointers you are done with them.  I do not recommend this route.

Comment: All the answers were great, but I will need a vector of pointers so I'm going to accept this reply. Thanks for the extra information.

Answer (score 5):

You are passing pointers to local variables to the vector here:

```
Element ice = Element("ice",1);
Element fire = Element("fire",2);
elements.push_back(&ice); 
elements.push_back(&fire);
```

When you exit the function, `ice`, and `fire` cease to exist, so you are left with dangling pointers.

The solution to this problem depends on whether you really need a vector of pointers. It might be simpler to have `std::vector<Element>`:

```
std::vector<Element> elements;
```

then

```
elements.push_back(Element("ice",1));
elements.push_back(Element("fire",2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You push dangling pointers into your vector:

```
void initialize() {
    Element ice = Element("ice",1);
    Element fire = Element("fire",2);
    elements.push_back(&ice); 
    elements.push_back(&fire);
}
```

here ice and fire is local variable. You push the address to the vector, then as final } is reached both get destroyed.  Later when you rereference this invalid pointer behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector is storing pointers to local variables that are created on the stack. When the function is finished, the memory occupied by these variables will be reclaimed. If you try to access the memory, you will get a segfault.

```
void initialize() {
    Element ice = Element("ice",1); // Local variable.
    Element fire = Element("fire",2); // Local variable.
    elements.push_back(&ice); 
    elements.push_back(&fire);
} // Ice and fire disappear.
```

Allocate the memory for the elements on the heap:

```
void initialize() {
    Element *ice = new Element("ice",1);
    Element *fire = new Element("fire",2); 
    elements.push_back(ice); 
    elements.push_back(fire);
}
```

Remember to free the memory when you are finished!

```
typedef std::vector<Element *>::iterator EIter;
for (EIter it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end(); ++it) {
    delete *it;
}
```